# powershell dir gets an error when looping thru the results

Tags: powershell, foreach, dir

This one alone does work.
If I try `HandleReport -ReportName "123456.pdf"` it says `matches`

```
function HandleReport 
{
  param ( [string] $ReportName = "" )

       if ( $ReportName  -match "(\d{6})." ) {
         $Result = $_ + " matches ..."
         write $Result
       }
}
```

Now I call it from a function which reads a directory:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $EventTypes.length; $i++) {
    # $FU_Dir is correct and does exist.
    dir $FU_Dir | foreach {
       $ReportName = $_.name
       HandleReport -ReportName $ReportName
   }
}
```

Now I get:

> Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] doesn't contain
>   a method named 'op_Addition'. At line:6 char:24
>   +          $Result = $_ + <<<<  " matches ..."
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound    matches ...

maybe the `$_.name` does not give back a string?

Comment: `"(\d{6})."` ... Did you want 6 digits followed by a period? You should use `"(\d{6})\."` so you have a literal period instead of any character.

Comment: thx a lot, now its working !!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the purpose of `$_` is in the function. You already pass a string to the function so it should work if you change it to:

```
function HandleReport 
{
  param ([string] $ReportName = "")

       if ($ReportName -match "(\d{6})." ) {
         $Result = "$ReportName matches ..."
         Write-Output $Result
       }
}
```